# Microsoft Excel and Microsoft Form Stop Synchronization

Tags: microsoft-excel, sync, forms

I have an Excel workbook on OneDrive and a Microsoft Form that should be in sync. I face an issue frequently, which is the disconnection between the workbook and the form. I read the following post and I guess the issue is because of the manual editing on the workbook. Sometimes, I modify the other sheets (not the form sheet) to do some calculations and draw some conclusions from the form responses. Every time the disconnection happens, I have to resync to a new workbook and repeat all the formulas there. Also, sometimes, some responses do not appear in the workbook and I have to resync to a new workbook again.

Post: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/how-to-ensure-your-form-and-workbook-are-in-sync-e7fd7e45-d63f-4b30-b2ed-76709fe35813

Is there any way to prevent this disconnection issue? It is a bit annoying to repeat everything every time this issue happens. Also, I cannot sync to an existing workbook.

If I create two different workbooks, one for the form responses (raw inputs) and another one for the calculations, will I avoid this issue? The second workbook will read its inputs from the main workbook.